# Unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW error in my php code

Tags: php, error-handling, syntax-error

I'm sure this is something really simple, but I'm getting an `unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW` syntax error for my code below. Can someone help me trouble shoot please?

Thanks

Osu

```
// Set timezone
date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Melbourne'); 

// Set timestamps to compare
$tts                        = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');      // Today's timestamp
$fts                        = '2014-29-01 12:00:00';    // Final 'end' timestamp
$fts24                      = '2014-28-01 12:00:00';    // Last 24 hours timestamp

// Set conditions
$show24                     = false;
$show                       = false;

    // $tts must be between $fts24 and $fts
    if( $tts => $fts24 && $tts =< $fts ) {
        $show24 = true;
    }
    // $show24 must be false (don't show last 24 hours banner) and $tts must be before $fts
    if( $show24 == false && $tts =< $fts ) {
        $show = true;
    }

// Show either general or last 24hrs banner
if($show24) : ?>

    <a href="#url1" id="banner">
        <img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/image24.jpg" alt="image" width="500" height="62" />
    </a>

<?php elseif($show): ?>

    <a href="#url2" id="banner">
        <img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/image.jpg" alt="image" width="500" height="62" />
    </a>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: `=>` is not valid. Use `>=` instead.

Comment: What happened to the minimal understanding close verbiage? Were feelings hurt?

Comment: Curious, down-voted I'm assuming because it was too simple a question for you?

Comment: Yes, syntax error questions aren't helpful. As evidence by the related column. It's full of people who had the same problem yet you still couldn't find a solution so you posted yet another dupe.

Comment: Fair enough, can you recommend a place where these sorts of questions are appropriate according to your rules? Would be good to know a place where I won't get flamed for a simple syntax oversight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's here:

```
if( $tts => $fts24 && $tts =< $fts ) {
```

change it to:

```
if( $tts >= $fts24 && $tts <= $fts ) {
```

If you're getting the same error in the future, you would find it pretty easy by searching your code (Ctrl+F) for the "=>" or "=<" appearance.

Comment: The second should also be `<=` instead of `=<`

Comment: Didn't notice this, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out Yami, oversight on my behalf. Your help is much appreciated.